# Why does class not registered error occur when running SSIS packages from ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, ssis

I run ssis package from my asp.net application. When it's running on my local machine (32-bit OS), everything is working fine.
but when I published my site on remote computer (64-bit OS) I was getting run-time error:

```
Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS, Version=10.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot
find the file specified.
```

I put **`Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll`** and **`Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap.dll`** into the bin folder of my web site.

After that I had the next error:

```
 “An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format”
```

I  turned on " Enable 32-Bit Applications" option on iis for application pool and changed platform target to x86 in the properties of a project.

And now I have the following error:

```
 Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {BA785E28-3D7B-47AE-A4F9-4784F61B598A}
 failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered 
 (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
```

Any ideas how to fix that?
OR may be I'm moving in wrong direction?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are the versions of SQL server the same in both environments? Sounds like one could be 2005 and the other 2008...??

Comment: the versions of sql server are the same in both environments - it's 2008

Comment: You need to have the SQL Server Integration Services components installed on that machine. Piece-meal copying of the DLLs is not going to work. Additionally, there may be licensing implications of installing SSIS there so be sure to check with your license compliance person to make sure you haven't just added another Enterprise Edition of SQL Server into the domain-that'd be an expensive mistake.

Comment: I am getting this error while, from a SSMS 2012 I am trying to connect to SSIS 2014. When I upgrade the client SSMS 2012 to 2014 it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

#### MSDN reference:

Read the topic *[Understanding the Differences between Local and Remote Execution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403348.aspx)* on MSDN to understand the concept of running the packages remotely

```
You can only run a package outside the development environment on a 
computer that has Integration Services installed
```

The server that hosts your package should have **`Integration Services`** installed. Please consult Microsoft document on how the licensing model works with respect to *`Integration Services`*. Copying only the DLLs to the server where the package should run will not resolve the issue.

You can remotely invoke the package execution but you still need Integration Services on the server hosting the package.

#### MSDN blog article:

[*Running SSIS package programmatically*](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx) Read the point **1** in the article that describes about executing SSIS packages from ASP.NET

#### Quoted directly from the article:

Run package programmatically using SSIS Object Model. This is discussed in details in Books Online here: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136090.aspx

**`Benefits:`** Everything runs in process, it is very easy to set variables or modify package before executing it. You can also get events about package progress or ask it to stop by setting CancelEvent.

**`Drawbacks:`** Obviously this is local execution - you need to install SSIS on same machine where your app runs. This method also can't be used from .NET 1.1 application, unless it is moved to .NET 2.0 (which should be very easy to do, and in my experience improves the performance as well).

**`ASP.NET specific:`** The impersonation context does not get passed to additional threads SSIS package creates, so the data source connections will not be impersonated. Also, ASP.NET can be configured to recycle the worker process in case it consumes too much memory to improve availability of ASP.NET application. Since SSIS is likely to consume a lot of memory if you have lots of data, it can trigger this recycling and lower reliability of your application.

Answer (score 1):

**Some Background**
This works on your local machine because your SSIS package build version matches the Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll version you have in ASP.NET project. Now, you need to match the library versions from your SSIS build package to your Microsoft.SqlServer.ManagedDTS.dll versions. The versions must match and the 32-bit versus 64-bit libraries must match as well.

**Answer**
An easy way to do this is: Add SSIS script task to your package (on your remote server) and click the 'Edit Script' button. Now, look in the SSIS library references and you should see the version that the SSIS package loaded. That is the one you need to compile with ASP.NET project. This Script tasks can be deleted afterwards.