# SSIS package not getting desired output

Tags: c#, ssis

i created an SSIS package and put in a server location and also a text file which is also in the same location where the .dtsx exist.Then i tried to call the SSIS package from my local machine using C# code.What the package is doing is taking data from the text file and storing in Database.I always get Failure message on package execution.Here is what i tried

```
  Application app = new Application();
        Package package = null;
        try
        {

            string fileName = @"\\192.168.1.1\\Mypath\\file.txt";
            package = app.LoadPackage(@"\\192.168.1.1\\Mypath\\Package.dtsx", null);
            Variables vars = package.Variables;
            vars["FileName"].Value = fileName;
            DTSExecResult results = package.Execute();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            package.Dispose();
            package = null;
        }
```

Comment: And the specific failure message is? If you open your package using BIDS/SSDT and execute it, does it work? Need more information

Comment: i dont have integration services installed in my machine.... but when i tried to run the same in the local machine which is having the origianl package,its working fine

Comment: That's your problem. You can't run an Integration Services Package on a machine without having installed SQL Server Integration Services

Comment: possible duplicate of [Installing SSIS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690945/installing-ssis)

Comment: Better answers for duplicate but no accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14897461/why-does-class-not-registered-error-occur-when-running-ssis-packages-from-asp-ne/14897635#14897635 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17603892/deploy-ssis-packages-developed-using-sql-server-data-tools-for-visual-studio-201/17604041#17604041 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768560/ssis-installation-on-application-server-vs-database-server-which-is-right-opti/18769663#18769663

Comment: no SQL Server Integration Services is installed in a machine ,i am just trying to run that package from my machine.

Comment: But you don't have SSIS installed on the machine that is executing the code to run SSIS. The Integration Services assemblies are not part of the base .NET framework. Instead, they come with a licensed installation of SQL Server. I understand the packages are installed on Server A but you *cannot* run the SSIS on Machine B (your computer) unless you have a licensed installation on Machine B. This is why I've VtC this as a duplicate. The linked questions cover this in detail. Could you help me understand why your case is different?